# Deploy Web Application to Apache Http Server and Tomcat in one go

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

I am looking to front apache http server infront of tomcat 7, to render my static contents for better performance and scalability.

Now using pom, I was able to deploy to tomcat complete war.

But I could not find any plugin which will start http server and deploy static content to it.

Basically I looking to filter static resources and deploy it to http server while dynamic contents in the form of .war file to tomcat.

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <keystoreFile>../classes/.keystore</keystoreFile> 
                <keystorePass>someSecret</keystorePass>
                <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                <ajpPort>8009</ajpPort>
               </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I looking for something similar with embedded apache http server plugin or stuff.

Well other reason to redeploy on the fly is the static resources has a build based key, which will help to invalidate client side cache on every new build.

Some other solution which I already have is point my static resource folder inside tomcat webapp thru apache htaccess file as root and use it, but I have to manually change the static folder name every time new build is generated in this case.

Comment: I think this is good question but now project is already doing so, may be in new project. Also I guess native apnr is not available with such embedded tomcat? This can be on a separate thread instead of distracting from topic here. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to use maven-antrun-plugin.
You could define an Ant task that copy the static resources in the remote http server and bind it to the deploy phase of the maven lifecycle.